# Faxen's Law Proof

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics

Been working on this for a couple weeks and have had no dice. Does anyone know of a nice way to prove Faxen's law (force on a sphere in a fluid flow)? Particularly using the reciprocal theorem? Here is the link to what Faxen's law is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax%C3%A9n%27s_law

In particular the first law:
$$\mathbf{F} = 6 \pi \mu a \left[ \left( 1 + \frac{a^2}{6} \nabla^2\right) \mathbf{u}' - (\mathbf{U} - \mathbf{u}^\infty) \right]$$
So far everything I have researched seems very complicated involving an extremely long employment of stokeslets and stresslets. Any guidance would be great.

Comment: There are two Faxen's Laws mentioned on that Wikipedia page.  At the very least you need to clarify which one you're interested in (and ideally please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to show it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward development I've seen of the Faxén laws, at least for the first one you mention, is in Kim and Karrila's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486442195) which precisely uses the Lorentz reciprocal theorem.

Although I won't reproduce it exactly, I'll mention the key conceptual aspects and you can take it from there:

1. Consider the general form of the Lorentz reciprocal theorem: $$\oint_S \vec{v}_1\cdot\left(\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_2\cdot\vec{n}\right)dS\,-\int_V \vec{v}_1\cdot\left(\nabla \cdot\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_2\right)dV = \oint_S \vec{v}_2\cdot\left(\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_1\cdot\vec{n}\right)dS\,-\int_V \vec{v}_2\cdot\left(\nabla \cdot\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_1\right)dV$$ where $\vec{v}_i$ represents the fluid velocities and $\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_i$ represents the fluid stress tensor for the $i$th solution of a given Stokes flow problem.
2. Take your $\vec{v}_1$ and $\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_1$ to represent the solution for a spherical particle translating with constant velocity $\vec{U}$ in a quiescent infinite fluid. Note $\nabla\cdot\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_1 = \vec{0}$ everywhere in the fluid.
3. Take your $\vec{v}_2$ and $\bar{\bar{\sigma}}_2$ to represent the solution for a stationary spherical particle embedded in a fluid with a Stokeslet present at some position $\vec{y}$ not inside the spherical particle. Note $\vec{v}_2 = \vec{0}$ everywhere on $S$.
4. Simplify the expression above by using the singularity solutions for a sphere, in particular for $\vec{v}_1$, in order to pull out the first Faxén law for a sphere.

The derivation of the other Faxén laws follow from similar constructions when one considers the singularity solutions for the object under consideration (in your case, a sphere).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, I have been working through this problem for the past couple of weeks and I think that there is some issue that is glossed over in comparing the two solutions. The point force is at a fixed point y but, in the scheme where the sphere is moving  at velocity U, there is no time dependence. I am not sure that the solution makes sense without this being taken into consideration. But I am really not sure.

Comment: If your concern is that you are obtaining a time dependence somewhere, then you know you shouldn’t because Stokes’s law relates forces to velocities and not to accelerations. You should be able to analyze both situations in “steady cases”, sometimes by analyzing the problem in frames where everything is time-independent (i.e. think of problem 1 in an inertial frame with speed $-\vec{U}$.

Comment: wow, your responded really quick! So I don't understand, since the point force is fixed at a location y, how the sphere moving in some direction relative to it, doesn't create a time dependency. Is the point force moving along with the sphere at a constant distance from the radius?

Comment: The sphere in solution 2 (for the point force) is fixed and stationary. In that case you’re studying the flow generated by the point force on the fluid with the solid sphere in it.